# Using Aurelia CLI with the new webpack option, how would I add a reference to aurelia-auth

Tags: typescript, webpack, aurelia, aurelia-auth

I set up a new Aurelia project using the latest aurelia-cli. I chose to use webpack and TypeScript. It appears there is not much in the way of documentation when it comes to adding plugins into a project when using webpack. I would like to add aurelia-auth in. I tried adding it to an aurelia section in my package.json:

```
  "aurelia": {
    "build": {
      "resources": [
        "aurelia-auth"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Then using it:

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'))
  .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-auth'), (baseConfig)=>{
     baseConfig.configure({});
  });
```

But it does not appear that everything made it in:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Unable to find module with ID:
>   aurelia-auth/auth-filter

What is the correct way to add references when using Aurelia CLI and webpack to bundle and run an application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Webpack:**

In the `webpack.config.js`, there is a `ModulesDependenciesPlugin` entry within the `plugins` property. Add aurelia-auth in there, e.g.:

```
new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
  'aurelia-testing': [ './compile-spy', './view-spy' ],
  'aurelia-auth': [ './auth-filter' ]
}),
```

**For RequireJS:**
You should add the plugin to your `aurelia.json`'s `build.bundles.dependencies` property.

Try the following:

```
    "dependencies": [
      ...,
      {
        "name": "aurelia-auth",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-auth/dist/amd",
        "main": "aurelia-auth"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: That works for the default RequireJS configuration, but when I set the module loader to Webpack there is no dependencies section in aurelia.json. I added it in to see if it would work, but no dice. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated my post with a webpack solution. Perhaps this makes it for you.

Comment: Wanted to comment here for anyone else here who is stupid - You'll need to be sure to add the ModuleDependenciesPlugin portion of the Aurelia Webpack plugin in order for this to work! I.E:

    const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');